# 3D Touch Quick Action For Same ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, quickaction

the entry `ViewController` for my application consists of two buttons: `weight` and `age`. In the main `ViewController`, this is the code that runs when you click the `weight` button:

```
@IBAction func weightSearch(_ sender: Any) {
//Weight button clicked
inputReset()
userInput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
userInput.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

And this is the code that runs when you click the `age` button:

```
@IBAction func ageSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    //Age button clicked
    inputReset()
    userInput.inputView = agePicker
    userInput.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

What I am trying to do is implement a two 3D Touch quick actions, one called `Weight Search` (which runs the code for `func weightSearch`) and the other called `Age Search` (which runs the code for `func ageSearch`). Here is what I have done so far:

1. In the `Info.plist` file, I have created a `UIApplicationShortcutItems` array, with two `Items` of type dictionary, and their respective `UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle` and `UIApplicationShortcutItemType`.
2. In my `AppDelegate.swift` file, I have added the preliminary quick-action code:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
   //3D touch features 
   }
   ```

My issue now is that I am unsure what code to write for my `AppDelegate.swift` file. All the tutorials I have watched and all the similar questions on this site deal with calling a different `ViewController` using the quick actions, not calling different functions on the same `ViewController. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because iOS is telling your `AppDelegate` that a Quick Action was selected by the user, you're free to do what you want with it. To get a reference to your `ViewController` you can just ask the `window` for the `rootViewController` (which will be your `ViewController`). You're free then to do what you need to.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
  guard let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController else { return }
  viewController.performSomeAction()
}
```

You could also future proof this a bit and crash when running in debug mode if some point in the future you changed to have a different type of view controller as the root:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
  guard let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController else { 
  assertionFailure("Wrong view controller type!") // This only crashes in debug mode
  return 
}
  viewController.performSomeAction()
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I was just wondering however how I could call the specific function from the main `ViewController`?

Comment: Just call whatever function you want where I'm calling `performSomeAction()`. That is the main view controlller, because it's the root view controller for the window.